# Fix position JSON from input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I have form input like this

```
<div class="new_form form-group"><input class="form-control" name="'+search_field+'['+isi+'][]" type="text" placeholder="Input new field '+isi+'"/></div>

<div class="new_form2 form-group"><select class="form-control select2" name="'+search_field+'['+isi+'][]" style="width: 100%;"><option value="TES">TESS</option></select></div>
```

and result JSON like

```
{
"FirstName",
"TES",
}
```

if i want the result like

```
{
"FirstName" : "TES"
}
```

how should i do?

Comment: Result JSON is not at all valid JSON

Comment: @Javascript_Lover Both JSON snippets are invalid JSON (no trailing comma allowed)

Comment: A form does not result in JSON. You will have to show your code that gets the form content and massage it.

Comment: my JSON 
{
  "_token": "eHHCMuIJ4XA7QaDDPywR1oTZIYxQV5WfWfBKzBz6",
  "resource_name": null,
  "method": "POST",
  "field1": {
    "key": "id",
    "value": "Object ID"
  },
  "field2": {
    "key": "Name",
    "value": {
      "array": [
        "FirstName",
        "LastName",
        "ur first name",
        "ur last name"
      ]
    }
  }
}

in "array" i want [ "Firstname": "ur first name" , "LastName" : "ur last name"  ]. how should i do?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek i use Laravel, for show the JSON i use in controller like return $request->all() and the result is my JSON in this question

Comment: Is the essence of your question:  How do I convert `[ "FirstName", "LastName", "ur first name", "ur last name" ]` into `{ "FirstName": "ur first name", "LastName",  "ur last name" }`?  Also, can you verify that the order of items in the source array is as I have stated?

Comment: @DhiemasGanisha Edit your question with all relevant details, do not add comments

Comment: @JonSG yup like that

Answer (score 0):

Let me restate what I think you objective is:

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "_token": "eHHCMuIJ4XA7QaDDPywR1oTZIYxQV5WfWfBKzBz6",
  "resource_name": null,
  "method": "POST",
  "field1": { "key": "id", "value": "Object ID" },
  "field2": { "key": "Name", "value": {
    "array": [ "FirstName", "LastName", "ur first name", "ur last name" ]
  }}
}
```

I would like to convert it to the following JSON:

```
{
  "_token": "eHHCMuIJ4XA7QaDDPywR1oTZIYxQV5WfWfBKzBz6",
  "resource_name": null,
  "method": "POST",
  "field1": { "key": "id", "value": "Object ID" },
  "field2": { "key": "Name", "value": {
    "array": { "FirstName": "ur first name", "LastName",  "ur last name" }
  }}
}
```

Here is a naive (me not knowing more details of your problem) approach:

```js
var myJSON = {
  "_token": "eHHCMuIJ4XA7QaDDPywR1oTZIYxQV5WfWfBKzBz6",
  "resource_name": null,
  "method": "POST",
  "field1": { "key": "id", "value": "Object ID" },
  "field2": { "key": "Name", "value": {
    "array": [ "FirstName", "LastName", "ur first name", "ur last name" ]
  }}
};

myJSON.field2.value.array = (function(jsArray){
  var jsObj = {};
  jsObj[jsArray[0]] = jsArray[2];
  jsObj[jsArray[1]] = jsArray[3];
  return jsObj;
})(myJSON.field2.value.array);

console.log(myJSON);
```